# using xslt to transform xml in a categorized layout

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BOOKS>
<BOOK category="Book">
    <TITLE image="./images/govnahDesign.jpg">Bible</TITLE>
    <PRICE>0.00</PRICE>
</BOOK> 
<BOOK category="Magazine">
    <TITLE image="./images/govnahDesign.jpg">Auto Mall</TITLE>
    <PRICE>10.00</PRICE>
</BOOK> 
<BOOK category="Magazine">
    <TITLE image="./images/govnahDesign.jpg">LyfeStyle</TITLE>
    <PRICE>40.00</PRICE>
</BOOK>
    </BOOKS>
```

And i'm trying to let it display like so:

```
Category: Book
   Bible
   <img>
   0.00
---------------------

Category: Magazine
   Auto Mall
   <img>
   10.00

   LyfeStyle
   <img>
   40.00
```

The XSL i have so far is outputting like so:

```
Category: Book
   Bible
   <img>
   0.00
---------------------

Category: Magazine
   Auto Mall
   <img>
   10.00
---------------------

Category: Magazine
   LyfeStyle
   <img>
   40.00
---------------------
```

Here is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="BOOKS/BOOK">

Category: <xsl:value-of select="@category"/>

<xsl:for-each select="@category">

<div class="item"><!--div has a float:left-->
    <xsl:value-of select="../TITLE"/>
    <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="../TITLE//@image"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
    Price: <xsl:value-of select="../PRICE"/><br />
    <button id="view" onclick="javascript:viewProduct()">View</button>
</div>
<hr class="clear"/>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping is usually achieved with Meunchan method. In SO you will find a lot of answers about. Here you have one possible solution which just make a small change to your xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

 <xsl:key name="bybookcategory" match="BOOKS/BOOK" use="@category"/>

 <xsl:template  match="BOOKS">
  <xsl:for-each select="BOOK[generate-id()=generate-id(key('bybookcategory', @category)[1])]">
   Category: <xsl:value-of select="@category"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('bybookcategory', @category)">

     <div class="item"><!--div has a float:left-->
      <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
      <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="TITLE//@image"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </img>
     Price: <xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/><br />
     <button id="view" onclick="javascript:viewProduct()">View</button>
     </div>
    <hr class="clear"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Govnah,

Without changing the XML, you can go a route like this:

http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Loop through your books but only the ones without a "following-sibling" that has the same category (i.e. the first of that category).  Then inside that loop, loop through the books that match the current category.

Can you modify your XML like so?  It is not impossible to do what you're asking but sometimes I find tweaking the XML to be a cleaner route.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BOOKS>
<CATEGORIES>
  <CATEGORY>Book</CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY>Magazine</CATEGORY>
</CATEGORIES>
<BOOK category="Book">
    <TITLE image="./images/govnahDesign.jpg">Bible</TITLE>
    <PRICE>0.00</PRICE>
</BOOK> 
<BOOK category="Magazine">
    <TITLE image="./images/govnahDesign.jpg">Auto Mall</TITLE>
    <PRICE>10.00</PRICE>
</BOOK> 
<BOOK category="Magazine">
    <TITLE image="./images/govnahDesign.jpg">LyfeStyle</TITLE>
    <PRICE>40.00</PRICE>
</BOOK> 
</BOOKS>
```

Comment: i'm not sure how many categories i will have in the end, so adding that to the xml might be a hassle.. The link u referred me to is very useful. thank you :) @empo's xsl provided works great